# Need to delete records with cascade and want them to store in history table via hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to delete records from main table and store it in history table(exact replica of main table ), though I can code it manually. But is their a standard procedure to achieve same in hibernate ??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) ([a good tutorial](http://marakana.com/s/easy_auditing_versioning_for_your_hibernate_entities_with_envers,115/index.html)).